# Некорректный вывод для контейнера иерархии классов

Tags: c++

Для классов А и В(А базовый класс для В) переопределен оператор <<.
Есть контейнер общий для них(хранятся объекты класса А и В), для вывода я испоьзую алгоритм copy но он выводит адрес, как его(copy) переделать что бы работал  коректно

```
vector<A*> a;
copy(a.begin(), a.end(), ostream_iterator(cout, " "));
```

Comment: реализуйте `operator <<(std::ostream, A const *)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Как вариант:
class A {
    //...
public:
    //...
    virtual void f(std::ostream& os, const char* d) { os << *this << d; }    
};
class B : public A {
    //...
public:
    //...
    void f(std::ostream& os, const char* d) { os << *this << d; }   

};
template <class In>
void
copy(In first, In last,  std::ostream& out, const char* delim = " " )
{
    for_each(first, last, [&](A* p) {p->f(out, delim);});
}
```

использование:

```
vector<A*> v;
v.push_back(new A());
v.push_back(new B());
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), cout);
//...
```

Comment: А зачем delim делать параметром `f`?

Comment: на  for_each(first, last, [&](A* p) {p->f(out, delim);}); кидает ошибку  syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'type specifier'

Comment: смотрите внимательно - вы что то упустили,  я проверил, нет никакой ошибки